# Where does iBooks store current position within a book?

Tags: ios, books

To be specific, I am speaking about epubs that I manually added to ibooks, not ones from the store. For an example, I download and import an epub, I read a few pages, I delete it. Some months later I import that same file again and iBooks remembers the exact page I was last on.

To try and localize this data, I think I have  such options to store this position in the cloud disabled and I tried logging into multiple different accounts both store and icloud.

Where is this positional data for iBooks on iOS stored?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Since you didn’t mention an operating system, I have tagged and editing this for macOS iBooks. Please make an edit if you can to list your exact os version and type of my guess was incorrect.

Comment: Good point on the operating system though your rephrasing was unnecessary. Edited.